# German Umlaute in PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, non-ascii-characters, html-escape-characters

**Situation**

1. I am writing a Ruby On Rails application in German and it is able to download PDF files.
2. User entered strings should be shown in the PDF. Like e.g. the cities:
   "Köln" & "München" (Cologne & Munich in english)
3. The ERB-views are displaying this properly probably because the special german characters ä, ü, ö & ß are known in UTF-8 (The head part of every page shows:
   meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8")

**Problem**

The PDF files are generated through a HTML file in the background rendering the strings and messing them up with some kind of glibberish characters.

**Solution idea?**

What to do to solve this? Is there a way to display German Umlaute properly in this PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself! I found out that the generated PDF was loading a separate template hence the page "didnt have meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8", which was obviously needed to work! Sorry for bothering!